# What is the opposite of a null set?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, terminology

In probability theory (and in measure theory), a null set is a set with measure $0$.

Is there a term for the opposite of this, ie. a set whose complement is a null set, or (equivalently, if we restrict ourselves to a probability space) a set with measure $1$?

Events with probability $1$ can be described as "almost certain," "almost sure," etc., but I'm looking for a word to describe the set itself. Would something like "full set" be a suitable phrasing? Or is there already a convention for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following a common pattern in mathematical language, "[co-null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conull_set)" is a reasonable term.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen both "co-null set" and "(set of) full measure" used here. Note that these are each a bit better than "measure $1$," since the latter doesn't mean what it should when the measure of the whole space isn't $1$ (consider the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ as opposed to just $[0,1]$ or similar).

I like the term "full set," but I've never heard it used.